# Powershell: Open HTM and Save As XLS

Tags: excel, powershell, save-as

is it possible to have Powershell open a .HTM and save as an .XLS. My HTM file is a table that I would like the formatting carried though to which rules out a CSV. I have tried various methods using save as however it just saves the file with the .XLS extension whilst still being an .HTM file. I believe I just need the middle part of the script below filled in with the Save As code. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
$Excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$FilePath = "C:\ScriptRepository\Results\Test.htm"
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$Excel.Visible = $true
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False

$Excel.Workbooks.Close()
$Excel.Quit()
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WorkBook)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
Remove-Variable -Name excel
```

Comment: Please provide some details on the `SaveAs` methods you've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When saving, pass the output file path and the enum `51`, which tells Excel to use the `xlsx` filetype.

Check out the [SaveAs documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx), and [XlFileFormat enumerations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) page for more info.

```
$OutFile     = "c:\mypath\to\my.xlsx"
$xlSLSXType  = 51
$workBook.SaveAs("$OutFile",$xlSLSXType)
```

Comment: Thankyou kindly gms0ulman, thats done the trick. I had to remove $Excel.Visible = $true for it to work however Excel was not required to be visible. Thankyou once again.